# Is there any way to get package names for types in Java while compiling from command line? And for types, can i get their available method list?

Tags: java, command-line, ide

I have to write java codes in text editor and then compile and run from command line in a test. As there is no suggestions or help available in text editor, only syntax highlighting can be used, i often could not remember correct package names for types. I won't have access to documentation also. So is there any way to get the possible package names using command line? And is it possible to get available methods for a type from command line too?

Edit:By packages i meant built in packages.

Comment: I'm guessing you're being forced to do things the hard way due to it being school (and have a poor teacher; there's literally no reason for this). Quite frankly, you're better off simply typing the classname into google or simply have a local copy of the JDK javadocs open in your browser.

Comment: Sadly i can't have access to javadocs, and of course not internet/google! I have been writing codes in java for a good amount of time, still the experience is not enough to get everything right.

Comment: what do you mean you can't have access to the javadocs? And *no one* writes code like you're describing. Not using the proper tools and reference is just silly.

Comment: I guess i have a bad luck, most of my uni teachers think they're being smart doing things like that.

Comment: Ugh. As I suspected. So sorry you have to deal with that nonsense. You know the old adage; those who can, do. Those who can't ... teach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of methods, you can easily find the methods of particular class just typing **"javap java.util.Scanner"**.Here I used Scanner class in util package.

Comment: Thanks! That solves a big problem for me. So i don't think it would be possible to get suggestion for missing package names as it is probably the smartness of IDE, but i guess there might be a way to get list of available packages in the same way we get the method list, is there any?

Comment: I am not discouraging you to use javap but use of documentation will help you more in improving your java programming.There is no need to download the documentation from Oracle website but you can make it yourself by just copying the src rar file from jdk folder to any place and just reach to that directory through command line then go to the package where java files are kept and just type **javadoc *.java** this will make the documentation for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools you could use:

- To find classnames, you find the path to the rt.jar file, and then run this:

  ```
     $ jar tvf .../rt.jar | less
  ```

  ... and use the less command's text search capability to find the class you are after.  (Or use some other convenient way to search the `jar tvf` output ...)

  The rt.jar file should be in the Java installation tree.
- To find the methods declared by a class, use `javap ... <classname>` giving the full classname.  (But note that you need to know the full classname, correctly spelled and capitalized!)

---

I'd also agree with @BrianRoach - this is not a fair test of a Java programmer's ability.  No employer would ever require / demand that a programmer memorize the the Java APIs.  The javadocs are essential for a programmer to do his job ... and testing his/her ability to program without them is pointless.

I hope your teacher ... or whoever ... is reading this.

(Now if you were just "paper programming" in a written exam or an interview, that is a bit different.  But then a fair marking / assessment scheme would not penalize you for not remembering package names and method names accurately.  Just like it would not penalize you for spelling errors, etc.)

Comment: It honestly makes me weep reading all the horrible programming exercises I see posted on SO. It makes you want to find the instructor responsible and take them down about 10 notches.